# Python MSAL Acquire Token by Auth Code Flow -- How do I get auth_response dict?

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, microsoft-dynamics, azure-ad-msal

I am writing a script in python to authenticate to my Dynamics web api app and be able to perform operations (get/patch/post, etc). I am trying to authenticate via authorization code flow but am stuck on how to get the auth_response argument, as the [MSAL documentation](https://msal-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#publicclientapplication) is vague regarding how to get it, only stating that the auth_ response is "A dict of the query string received from auth server". How do I get this to work properly? Or is there another authentication type you'd recommend? I will attach my code below. Thank you!

```
app = msal.ClientApplication(
    client_id,
    client_credential=None,
    authority=authority_url
)
```

```
session = requests.Session()
session.flow = app.initiate_auth_code_flow(scopes=scope_list, redirect_uri=redirect)

result = app.acquire_token_by_auth_code_flow(auth_code_flow = session.flow, auth_response = ???, scopes=scope_list)
```

I tried client credentials before and kept getting a 403 forbidden error. Auth code flow works to perform operations via Postman, I just need to get it running in Python. session.flow gives me a working dictionary for auth_code_flow, I am just missing the auth_response argument.